# Can't understand the notation of an exercise

Tags: functions, absolute-value

I can't understand the following notation: $|x^{2} - 4| x|+3|$.

My first guess would be: $|x^{2} - 4| \cdot 3x$ but it might not be the case... And I've never seen a function written this way.

Comment: This is the absolute value of $x^{2} - 4| x|+3|$?

Comment: $$abs( x^2 -4 \ abs(x) +3)$$

Comment: Thanks guys, it makes sense now...

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net, you included one to many vertical lines, namely, the one following 3.  Rather, the question addresses "the absolute value of $(x^2 -4|x| + 3)$."